# Why is the While loop in this python code not ending breaking?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

Hi I'm a little bit of a beginner and I'm trying run a while loop that sends notifications at a certain time then stop running once the notification is sent but every time I run the program the while loop is not ending. Does anyone know why? Here is the code:

```
def notify():
    with open('task.json') as file:
        data = json.load(file)

    tday = datetime.date.today()

    days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

    for task in data['Reminder']:
        for day in days:
            if day == task['Date']:
                dateIndex = days.index(day)
                if dateIndex == tday.weekday():
                    comment = f"You are suppose to work on {task['Task']} today"
                    Task.notification(comment)
                    print(f"You are suppose to work on your {task['Task']} on {task['Date']}" )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        timeAM = f'{now.hour}:{now.minute} AM'
        timePM = f'{now.hour - 12}:{now.minute} PM'
        with open('task.json') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
        for task in data['Reminder']:
            if timeAM == task['Time'] or timePM == task['Time']:
                notify()
                break
            else:
                pass
```

Comment: The `break` when it's run works on the `for` loop, to use it on the `while` you need to either move it from one indentation level or add another break after the `for`

Comment: Perhaps [`for ... else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) might be helpful. If you move your last block of code into a function `main` of its own (called at the entry point), `for ... else` here can make for a very elegant recursive `main`.